# In Android 10, is there a way to prioritize notifications (i.e. their lockscreen order) WITHIN the alert category?

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, android-10, notification-bar

In Android 7 (Nougat), there was a special option that allowed for improved granularity in managing **notification order**, see e.g. [Android Police - Android N Feature Spotlight: Full Importance Settings Offer Granular Control Of Notification Priority](https://www.androidpolice.com/2016/03/15/android-n-feature-spotlight-full-importance-settings-offer-granular-control-of-notification-priority/). I made extensive use of this feature but, alas, it has been dropped. Now on Android 10, I only find two notification classes, "alert" and "silent/gentle".

I have a lot of calendar reminders and messages that are **both** required to be alerted to me. However, I need the messages (Slack, Whatsapp, etc.) to be ON TOP of all the other notifications, especially on top of the calendar reminders, so that incoming messages do not get lost among the many reminders of a day.

Previously, in Android 7, this was readily feasible by giving the messenger apps "highest priority" and the calendar app "second-highest priority". Both generated palpable alert notifications, but the messenger notifications would always be moved to the top and remain there, even as new calendar reminders come in. Currently, the only way to move the reminders below the other notifications is to classify them as silent, which defies their very purpose.

Is there any way to change the order of notifications on a per-app basis **within** the alert category on Android 10? I looked extensively for an Xposed module or custom ROM that could do that. So far, in vain.

Comment: Gravity box "ultimate notification control" may be of some help (it's a pro feature) - not what you are looking for but as an alternative to some extent

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I've found is to scan active alerts for "now" in the time received.  Beware, sometimes there is no "now" item, I have no idea why.